# Indefinite integral involves Meijer G-function

Tags: reference-request, special-functions

The following integral

$$\int y^{l-1} G_{p,q}^{m,n}\left(z y \mid \begin{array}{c}
                                          \boldsymbol{a_{p}} \\
                                          \boldsymbol{b_{q}}
                                        \end{array} \right) dy=  y^{l} G_{p+1,q+1}^{m,n+1}\left(z y \mid \begin{array}{c}
                                         1-l, \boldsymbol{a_{p}} \\
                                          \boldsymbol{b_{q}},-l
                                        \end{array} \right)$$
is presented in Wolfram Functions Site 
http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/MeijerG/21/01/02/01/0002/

but i could not find another reference for this integral.

Comment: You case search DLMF (digital library of mathematical functions), it has a chapter on Meijer function, and it usually has links to all the sources

Comment: Have a look at https://dlmf.nist.gov/16.19

Comment: I have already searched these references and the result is nothing. Also, I could not find a reference for other properties and operations involve Meire G-function listed in Wolfram Functions Site.

Comment: Similar result can be obtained using identity 1.2.9 and differential property 1.3.12 represented in Mathai and Saxena 1973.